# Can't connect hyper-v VM to via Virtual Switch

Tags: hyper-v

On my computer, I created a Hyper-V VM and virtual switch from the Microsoft documentation using all the defaults a few months ago, everything was fine, I could see the real computer in the Network list and connect to the Internet.  I tried adding a second VM using the same virtual switch and now the original VM won't connect.    I've  removed the second VM, uninstalled and reinstalled Hyper-V, deleted all the VMs and virtual switches and started again, all with no luck.

The closest I've got to it working again is ticking "Enable virtual LAN identification for management operating systems" under the virtual switch which lets the VM see the real computer in the Network list, but the real computers network connection no longer works.   I untick the box and the network connection comes back and the real computer is removed from the Network list.

When I uninstalled Hyper-V and reinstalled, the VM was in the list, so I don't know if there are some settings that don't get removed on uninstall, I ran CCleaner to try clearing it all out with no change.

Any ideas how to completely uninstall Hyper-V with all it's hidden settings and details or how to fix the virtual switch issues?

Comment: How are you creating the virtual switch? How are you giving the VMs access to the virtual switch?

Comment: Using the wizard on the right and I've tried the script method and I'm setting it in the settings window.